# "Sarà un'eternità e mezza che non ti vedo!": Why use the present tense "vedo" to describe an already completed action?

Tags: tenses

Today I bumped into a friend of mine, an Italian native speaker, on the street I hadn't seen for quite a while. I'm pretty sure she said:

> Sarà un'eternità e mezza che non ti **vedo**!

Looking back on it, the tense used here piques my interest: despite the fact that we **have already seen** each other **just now**, what is the rationale for using the present tense "vedo" rather than the imperfect "vedevo"? It almost sounds like we have yet to meet in person (the state of not seeing each other is still ongoing) and our next encounter will be some time in the near future.

> {vs}: Sarà un'eternità e mezza che non ti **vedevo**!

I'm all the more curious, since in French and German we express the same idea in  complete different tenses, perfect tenses, conveying the sense of a completed action:

> Ça **faisait** longtemps qu'on ne s'**était** pas **vus** ! --- {*imperfect + past perfect*}
>
> Dich **habe** ich ja schon ewig nicht **gesehen**! --- {*present perfect*}

Comment: To Italian native speakers: in a context similar to one explained by the OP, do you see any difference between "Non ci vediamo da un bel po' di tempo" and "Non ci siamo visti da un bel po' di tempo"?

Comment: I have asked a similar question on Spanish.SE.

Comment: @Charo Hi. Actually, the way you phrased it in Spanish SE, "Ça **fait** longtemps qu'on ne s'**est** pas vus !", indicates that you two haven't met in person yet, just speaking on the phone or something for now, whereas with "Ça **faisait** longtemps qu'on ne s'**était** pas vus !" indicates that you have already met even if it's just a few seconds ago.

Comment: Well, I'm not an expert in French, so I really don't know, but searching "Ça fait longtemps qu'on ne s'est pas vus" on Google Books the first thing I've found is: https://books.google.es/books?id=uCg9U1PZqvwC&pg=PA65&dq=%22%C3%87a+fait+longtemps+qu%27on+ne+s%27est+pas+vus%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiXyp31msncAhXGJFAKHQ9IBSUQ6AEICjAA#v=onepage&q=%22%C3%87a%20fait%20longtemps%20qu'on%20ne%20s'est%20pas%20vus%22&f=false. But probably you have reason and there are some different nuances between this and your sentence.

Comment: But I've included your sentence in my Spanish question.

Comment: Now I've received [some answers](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/26971/19075).

Comment: @Charo To me "Non ci siamo visti da un bel po' di tempo" does not sound very grammatical. "Non ci siamo visti *per* un bel po' di tempo" is better.

Comment: I would say that in colloquial Italian the present tense can often (though not always) to express actions that are not necessarily happening in the present. This usage communicates more immediateness and is conveniently complemented with adverbs or other specifications that clarify the timing. It can also be done for future actions: "Domani vado al mare", which is "Tomorrow I am going to the seaside".

Comment: In a sense, when you use this type of present you want to say something like "This action is not happening just now, but it is so close that it belong to the present more than it belongs to the future or the past". If you say that you are going to the seaside tomorrow, you basically already preparing and waiting for it. If you have just seen your friend after an eternity and a half, it means that two minutes ago you really couldn't not see them.

Comment: @GiovanniMascellani:  It may be that way, but I think that your example about a future action expressed with present tense ("Domani vado al mare") is clearly explained in [grammars as "*presente pro futuro*"](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/indicativo-presente_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/), whereas I haven't found any explanation about the use of present to talk about a fact that happened very recently in the past.

Comment: @Charo In this case I would consider it under the "Presente abituale" label: in this colloquial meaning "vedersi" is often meant as a frequent activity (you usually see your friends every now and then). In this case it is negated, but that is the kind of action this it refers to. Just my feelings, unfortunately I do not know much about Italian grammar, I just know Italian...

Comment: @GiovanniMascellani: Yes, that's the same explanation that has been given in an answer to my  [analogous question in Spanish.SE](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/26971/19075).

Comment: @Charo Hi. As this discussion seems quite extended now, could you move it to Chat for further discussions?

Answer (score 1):

It is more clear in a sentence like "I don't see you since 1999" in Italian "Non ti vedo dal 1999". The example you reported above uses the present tense evaluating in the present the amount of time you've spent apart. It is colloquial.
We use too the past tense in a formal version like "We hadn't meet for several years". Here we use the verb "vedere" indicating the period in the past: "Non ci siamo visti per diversi anni".

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Answer (score 1):

To me, these "time-shifts" are much useful to enrich the verve of colloquial Italian:

- **immediately** upon meeting after a long time I would also say (more or less)

  > **Sarà (È)** un'eternità e mezzo che non ti **vedo**

  - on the contrary, after a while, talking about the long separation, I would say

    > **Sarà stata (Era)** ... che non ti **vedevo**/  **non ci siamo visti** per ..

where the use of the future (sarà) gives an "approximating" sense to the "one and half".
By the way, I much appreciate your friend's *hyperbole* of *"un'eternità e mezzo"*.